# Understand the $eq operator mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In most of my queries, i am not using the `$eq` operator when i should make an equality for a field.

I am guessing that if this operator exists, it's not for nothing... So i would like to know :

- Why / when should i use `$eq` ?
- Regarding performance, is it better or worse than letting the field empty ?

You can answer both questions based on this example :

`result_without_eq = my_collection.find({"_id": "anyID"})`

`result_with_eq = my_collection.find({"_id": {"$eq": "anyID"}})`

Comment: "Specifying the $eq operator is equivalent to using the form { field: <value> } except when the <value> is a regular expression."
From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)

Comment: Thanks Ramit, i have also read that it has some security safety for user input, we should use the $eq. So regarding performances nothing is said, maybe this is strickly equivalent...